# Spring Boot Swagger: How to ignore certain API's from swagger based on spring profile?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, spring-restcontroller, springfox, spring-restdocs

Currently, there are certain private API's in my controller class which I need to ignore them in my production environment, whereas needed in the QA and Dev environments.

I'm using @ApiIgnore annotation from spring fox to achieve this on a global level. Is there a way where I can execute this annotation based on spring boot environment variable?

Or any other solution to tackle this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
@Autowired private Environment environment; 
....
this.environment.getActiveProfiles();
```

to get the current profile and then create `Docket` objects in your swagger configuration class based on the active profile.

Comment: Thanks it worked. if (Arrays.stream(env.getActiveProfiles()).anyMatch(e -> (e.equalsIgnoreCase("dev")))) {
   requestHandlerSelector = and(not(withClassAnnotation(ApiIgnore.class)),
     not(withMethodAnnotation(ApiIgnore.class)));
  } else {
   requestHandlerSelector = any();
  }

Comment: @AnandKuklkarni Can you please take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49835394/swagger-springfox-custom-sort-comparator-to-order-the-apis